# Tkinter Listbox and Scrollbar not displaying

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having this issue where the scroll bar is not displaying on the listbox. I do not know what the issue is as.

I believe the issue is originating from the Scrollbar variables as the Listbox appears to be displaying and functioning properly.

The output is displaying the listbox with no scrollbar on the right (as set)

Here is the Listbox with the for loop however, it is displaying the wrong dimensions
[image]

Here is the code:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import datetime

global time 
time = datetime.datetime.now()

class main:
    def __init__(self,master):

        self.master = master

def search_user_sql(self):

        self.search_user_sqlf = Frame(self.master, height=300, width =200)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.search_user_sqlf)
        scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT,fill = BOTH)

        myList = Listbox(self.search_user_sqlf, yscrollcommand= scrollbar.set)
        myList.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 2)

        scrollbar.config( command = myList.yview )

self.search_user_sql()

root = Tk()
root.title("Gym Membership System")
main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code so we can test it please?

Comment: Sure. I edited the code so you can test it @ThaerA

Comment: This code won't run at all (undefined names: self, main).

Comment: @Lach The code above doesn't work at all. What is self.search_user_sql()? and main(root)?

Comment: I have inserted more of my code so it functions. Let me know if it still doesn't run @ThaerA

Comment: This code still doesn't run.

Comment: @Lach There are still errors in your code. How are you displaying the frame without a pack()? Anyways, I posted an example below. If you're still facing issues let us know but share a working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pack the frame to display it. To pack() the frame with the correct size settings, try:

```
search_user_sqlf = Frame(master, height=300, width=200)
search_user_sqlf.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
search_user_sqlf.pack_propagate(0)
```

Here is how to attach a scrollbar to list set in a frame in Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()


search_user_sqlf = Frame( master, width=400, height=400)
search_user_sqlf.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
search_user_sqlf.pack_propagate(0)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(search_user_sqlf)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
myList = Listbox(search_user_sqlf, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for line in range(100):
   myList.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

myList.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH , expand = 2)
scrollbar.config( command = myList.yview )

mainloop()
```

Comment: @Lach Your code doesn't work to begin with. If you run the code in my answer it should work. It will give you a good idea of how to attach a scrollbar to a list box in Tkinter. If you want us to debug your code, please share a working version of your code.

Comment: It is 600 lines. I tried to section off the part that the error is occurring @Thaer!

Comment: @Lach I understand but the code for the interface is not working. We can't debug or fix it if the entire thing doesn't work. Did you run pack() on your frame? Did you set the fill on your scrollbar to fill = Y and pack it the right way >>>scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)?

Comment: 'scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT,fill = BOTH)' Here is my .pack() @ThaerA

Comment: @Lach Did you try to change it to scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)?

Comment: Yes I have but the listbox doesnt seem to be displaying

Comment: @Lach Did you add self.search_user_sqlf.pack() AFTER self.search_user_sqlf = Frame(self.master, height=300, width =200)?  you have to .pack() your FRAME.

Comment: Yes @ThaerA it displays however, it does not fit the dimensions stated in the frame. It only shows the listbox in a small dimension

Comment: @Lach Was the issue with the Frame.pack()? Can you share a screenshot of how it looks now?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the listbox

Comment: @Lack I updated the answer with how to display the frame with correct size. If that was helpful, please set the questions as answered. If not, let us know what's not working

Comment: It Stretches the listbox and fits vertically but not horizontally (width is still the same)

Comment: @Lach Run the example I posted. You'll see that it stretches both vertically and horizontally. See what's different in your code and try changing it.